# Find the missing group entry in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below table:

```
 Declare @t table (Name nvarchar(80))
 
 Insert into @t values 
 
 ('ABC:CE')
 ,('ABC:LI')    
 ,('ABC:XP')    
 ,('ABD:CE')    
 ,('ABD:LI')    
 ,('ABE:LI')    
 ,('ABE:XP')    
 ,('ABF:XP')
```

I have 3 categories CE,LI,XP. I wanted to check which group is missing in the name.

I tried below Query:

```
 select  SUBSTRING(Name,1,charindex(':',Name)-1),count(1) as grplist from @t
 group by SUBSTRING(Name,1,charindex(':',Name)-1)
 having count(1) <3
```

Expected output:

```
Name    
ABD:XP  
ABE:CE  
ABF:LI  
ABF:CE
```

Can you guys help me where I am going wrong this:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Declare @t table (Name nvarchar(80))
 
 Insert into @t values 
 
 ('ABC:CE')
 ,('ABC:LI')    
 ,('ABC:XP')    
 ,('ABD:CE')    
 ,('ABD:LI')    
 ,('ABE:LI')    
 ,('ABE:XP')    
 ,('ABF:XP');


WITH DataSource ([group], [category]) AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING([Name], 1, CHARINDEX(':', [Name]) - 1)
          ,SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX(':', [Name]) + 1, 100)
    FROM @t
)
SELECT DISTINCT G.[group], C.[category]
FROM DataSource G
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [category]
    FROM DataSource
) C
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM DataSource DS
    WHERE DS.[group] = G.[group]
        AND DS.[category] = C.[category]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Probably `SELECT category FROM (VALUES ('CE'), ('LI'), ('XP')) v (category)` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT [category] FROM DataSource` is more appropriate here (e.g. table `@t` with only one row `('ABC:CE')`). If I remember correctly, `VALUES()` table value constructor was introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @Zhorov Make sense if  the categories are known. It will perform better for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You want to select the values that are *not* in the table. For this to happen, you must first create these values. You do this with a cross join:

```
select n.name + ':' + c.category as missing
from (select distinct substring(name, 1, charindex(':', name) - 1) as name from @t) n
cross join (values ('CE'), ('LI'), ('XP')) c(category)
except
select name from @t
order by missing;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c99228/4

Answer (score 0):

I see there's an answer here already but here's my take, looks similar mine may be less efficient but hey more the merrier :)

```
 Declare @t table (Name nvarchar(80)) 
Insert into @t values  
 ('ABC:CE')
 ,('ABC:LI')    
 ,('ABC:XP')    
 ,('ABD:CE')    
 ,('ABD:LI')    
 ,('ABE:LI')    
 ,('ABE:XP')    
 ,('ABF:XP')

Declare @c table (Cat nvarchar(2)) 
Insert into @c values  
 ('CE')
 ,('LI')  
 ,('XP')


SELECT 
    possible.prefix
    ,possible.Cat
    ,possible.prefix + ':' + possible.Cat
    --,selector.Prefix
    --,selector.suffix

FROM
(
select  
    SUBSTRING(Name,1,charindex(':',Name)-1) as prefix
    ,SUBSTRING(Name,charindex(':',Name)+1,2) as suffix
from @t

) as selector
right Join 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        SUBSTRING(Name,1,charindex(':',Name)-1) as prefix
    --  ,SUBSTRING(Name,charindex(':',Name)+1,2) as suffix
        ,Cat
    FROM @t
    cross join @c
) possible
ON selector.prefix = possible.prefix
and selector.suffix = possible.Cat
where selector.suffix is null
```